Vector/axial current and vector/axial transformation
As is well known, in particle physics, the vector current is defined as a current of the form
$$J_V^\mu = \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi $$
and the axial current as
$$J_A^\mu = \bar{\psi} \gamma^5 \gamma^\mu \psi $$
These currents are important for establishing, for example, the charged weak current as one of the V-A form.
Now, in Nuclear Physics theories that relate the interactions of elementary particles with the nucleus (chiral theories, Skyrme model), which are commonly based on group theory, it is established that a vector transformation is
$$U \rightarrow MUM^\dagger, \quad M,U \in SU(2) $$
and an axial transformation is
$$U \rightarrow MUM, \quad M,U \in SU(2) $$
By similarity, a charged current associated with the nucleus is also of the V-A form.
Therefore, my question is the following: what is the relationship between these transformations and the currents, aside from the name? What has led to the idea that they are related?

Linked.

They are not just related, they are identical, joined at the hip. I'll illustrate by the original legendary 2-flavor chiral model, with the chiral group $\text{SU}(2)_L \times \text{SU}(2)_R$. This group is spontaneously broken down to $\text{SU}(2)_V$, by the QCD vacuum: it is realized ''nonlinearly'', in the Nambu–Goldstone mode, i.e., the $Q_V$ annihilate the vacuum, but the $Q_A$ do not! This is visualized nicely through a geometrical argument based on the fact that the Lie algebra of $\text{SU}(2)_L\times\text{SU}(2)_R$ is isomorphic to that of SO(4).
Your currents as given are malformed into singlets. They need isospin triplet matrices τ to make sense into the current algebra underlying the chiral picture:
$$\begin{cases} q_L \mapsto q_L'= M_L q_L = \exp{\left(- i {\boldsymbol{\theta}}_L \cdot \tfrac{\boldsymbol{\tau}}{2} \right)} q_L \\ q_R \mapsto q_R'= M_R q_R = \exp{\left(- i \boldsymbol{ \theta}_R \cdot \tfrac{\boldsymbol{\tau}}{2} \right)} q_R \end{cases},$$
where  τ  denote the three Pauli matrices in the flavor space and θL, θR are the corresponding rotation angles for the L and R groups, respectively.
The corresponding symmetry group $\text{SU}(2)_L\times\text{SU}(2)_R$ is the chiral group, controlled by the six conserved currents
$L_\mu^i = \bar q_L \gamma_\mu \tfrac{\tau^i}{2} q_L$,  $R_\mu^i = \bar q_R \gamma_\mu \tfrac{\tau^i}{2} q_R$,
which can equally well be expressed in terms of the vector and axial-vector currents you should have written, $V_\mu^i = L_\mu^i + R_\mu^i$ , $A_\mu^i = R_\mu^i - L_\mu^i$.
The corresponding conserved charges generate the algebra of the chiral group,
$$\left[ Q_{I}^i,  Q_{I}^j \right] = i \epsilon^{ijk} Q_I^k \qquad \qquad \left[ Q_{L}^i,  Q_{R}^j \right] = 0,$$
with $I=L,R$, or, equivalently,
$$\left[ Q_{V}^i,  Q_{V}^j \right] = i \epsilon^{ijk} Q_V^k, \qquad \left[ Q_{A}^i,  Q_{A}^j \right] = i \epsilon^{ijk} Q_V^k, \qquad \left[ Q_{V}^i,  Q_{A}^j \right] = i \epsilon^{ijk} Q_A^k.$$
Application of these commutation relations to hadronic reactions dominated current algebra calculations in the early seventies of the last century.
So the chiral field $U$ transforms differently on the left and the right,
$$M_L U M_R^\dagger=\exp(i\boldsymbol{\theta}_A\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}/2 -i\boldsymbol{\theta}_V\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}/2 )~ U ~\exp(i\boldsymbol{\theta}_A\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}/2 +i\boldsymbol{\theta}_V\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau}/2 ).$$
θA= 0 , then, manifestly yields your vector transformation, while  θV =0 the axial one.
